# convert horizontal side by side to vertically stacked 3D video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, 3d

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934) and [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg?newreg=08cf71ca624344a09f50ef640118e6cd) post explaining how to crop and stack videos using `ffmpeg`.

My question is - is there an easy (preferably one step) way to turn a horizontally stacked video into a vertically stacked one?

And is there a Linux-way to re-encode given 3D video formats into others?

**Edit:**

with Mulvyas help I wrote a [script](https://github.com/frans-fuerst/magic/raw/master/LR2TB.py) which does the converting stuff and creates a text file with meta information needed by the Gear VR video player.

Note: you need a recent version of `ffmpeg` for the `vstack` filter - version 2.6 which is installed with Fedora 22 is too old. Version 2.8.3 has `vstack` available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just integrate all filtering into one command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top]; \ 
[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom]; \
[top][bottom]vstack[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

Edit: this command below scales and pads the output to 2000x2000

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top]; \
[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom]; \
[top][bottom]vstack,\
scale=iw*min(2000/iw\,2000/ih):ih*min(2000/iw\,2000/ih), \
pad=2000:2000:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

Comment: I have a source video named `input.mp4` which I first turn into `left.mp4` and `right.mp4`. If I understand your command assumes these files to exist in the first place.

Comment: modified for single input

Comment: can you scale and pad the output at the same time, too?

Comment: sure. what do you want done?

Comment: I'd want to pad the output to be squared (same width as height). Currently I'm running `-vf "pad=width=in_h:height=in_h:x=in_w/2:y=0:color=black"` on the output. And additionally I'd like to have a fixed width (and height) of e.g. 2000 pixel

Comment: Did you also want to scale the video?